# MySQL RAND() strange behaviour

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to obtain a random row from the result of an SQL query.

My query is as follows

```
SET @rank = 0;
SELECT * FROM(
     SELECT (@rank:=@rank+1) AS num, ...
     FROM ...
     WHERE ....) as raw
WHERE raw.num = FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * @rank)) LIMIT 1
```

The general idea being that each row of the table from the inner query result is given a unique number (num). I have manually checked that this is indeed the case and that every row is numbered.

The last line is causing me distress. As it stands, `WHERE num = FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * @rank)) LIMIT 1` is returning what I want - only half the time. It appears to be returning random rows within the correct range (which for the example I am testing the query on is 0-1299). However, one in every three queries returns absolutely nothing.

Ok, so I thought maybe it was a double precision issue, so I tried using `>=` as follows: `WHERE num >= FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * @rank)) LIMIT 1`. The result in this case is confusing me. With this code I always get a result, but the number of the row returned is always < 100.

So if we call FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * @rank)) `x`. When I use `=` rather than `>=` it confirms that `x` must (in some cases) be equal to numbers greater than 1000. However, when using `>=`, the fact that the condition is satisfied means that x must always be less than 100?

What's going on? or how else can I solve my problem

Comment: I think that `RAND()` function may be getting called multiple times, once for each row from `raw`. If that's the case, your equality test is chasing a moving target. Try initializing it once. (See my answer.)

Comment: As noted in one of the answers, `RAND()` is (probably - the function can't be marked `DETERMINISTIC` after all) being run multiple times per query.  There may also be some double-precision stuff cropping up too; I'd probably try to actually cast to an integer value, instead of `FLOOR()`, and add the 1 outside that function (assuming that the first row number is actually 1, and not 0).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that the `RAND()` function in your query is being called multiple times, once for each row returned from `raw`. If that's what's happening, then it's possible that it won't find any rows that satisfy the predicate, since it is comparing each row to a different target. (Is the first row the fifth row? Is the second row the third row? etc.)

I would move the call to RAND() and the initial assignment of @rank to the beginning of the query, something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM(
     SELECT (@rank:=@rank+1) AS num, ...
     FROM (SELECT @rand := RAND(), @rank := 0) r
     CROSS JOIN ...
     WHERE ....) as raw
WHERE raw.num = FLOOR(1 + @rand * @rank) LIMIT 1
```

-- or, in keeping with your pattern of using a separate SET statement --

```
SET @rand = RAND();
SET @rank = 0;
SELECT * FROM(
     SELECT (@rank:=@rank+1) AS num, ...
     FROM ...
     WHERE ....) as raw
WHERE raw.num = FLOOR(1 + @rand * @rank) LIMIT 1
```

(I happen to prefer the former, as it runs as a single statement; it's not dependent on user variables being set outside of the SELECT statement.)

But either of those should make sure that the call to the `RAND()` function is happening exactly once (at the beginning of your query).

Other than that, I don't have a good explanation as to the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: Tried your exemple, it dosn't get the mysterius empty results, and i think i learned a few things on the way, thanks, hope Roger also like it :-)

Comment: I think I prefer your first one myself.  DB2 doesn't let me mess with variables like you're doing, but I _do_ have access to the OLAP function `ROW_NUMBER()`, which will work nicely.  Personally, I'd probably try to pull out the `1 +` to _outside_ the `FLOOR()` function (and maybe just flat truncate to an integer type), just to attempt to remove floating point problems.

Comment: Thank you! I think you are right, the rand() function was being called multiple times. I have changed my query as per your recommendations and I'm seeing the results I expect.

Answer (score 0):

why not just use?:

```
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

if not you may want to read:
http://akinas.com/pages/en/blog/mysql_random_row/

**EDIT**
tested your query, and i got this udd output:

```
mysql> SET @rank = 0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM(
    ->     SELECT (@rank:=@rank+1) AS num, id
    ->     FROM (
    ->         SELECT 1 AS id UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3
    ->         ) as abc
    ->     ) as raw
    -> WHERE raw.num = @rownr := FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * @rank)) LIMIT 1;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @rownr;
+--------+
| @rownr |
+--------+
|      1 |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: That will be slow for very large tables, because MySQL has to create a temporary table holding all the rows in the result set, and assign a random number to each one, and then sort them. There are more efficient approaches.

Comment: dose it sort all, or dose it stop after finding the limited number, in this case the lowest one?

Comment: you make a good point, a full sort operation is not required in the case of a LIMIT 0,1, that has a chance to "short circuit" at the lowest one. But that wouldn't be the case for a more general LIMIT m,n clause/

Comment: @spencer7593 - how does it know which row is the 'lowest' one?  If `RAND()` is being called multiple times per statement, there's a possibility that you have duplicate values being generated, which could potentially include the 'lowest' value - **and the optimizer has no way to tell**.  Even if you'd only unique values (a terrible thing, actually), this doesn't necessarily help any - the function only generates values in the range [0, 1), but the potential range is **MUCH** larger, meaning that it wouldn't be able to discern the 'lowest' value anyways.

Comment: @X-Zero: I was addressing the comment from Puggan, which suggested that a "FULL SORT" operation was not necessary.  That is, MySQL might be able to optimize an `ORDER BY x LIMIT 1` with a single scan of the result set, and could bypass the operation of sorting the entire set. Yes, as I said in my previous comment, the `RAND` function would still get called on every row. The uniqueness of values returned by `RAND` doesn't matter. An ORDER BY is going to sort all of the values (unique or not). The question is really whether MySQL optimizes the LIMIT 1 by avoiding a complete sort.

Comment: @spencer7593 - Ah, sorry, yeah, you're right.  Don't know if it's that smart, though.

Comment: @X-Zero: I think you are right.  I don't think the MySQL optimizer is that smart. It was just something that Puggan suggested. Even if it was that smart, just having the value of `RAND()` assigned to every row is going to be relatively expensive on large resultsets, even without a sort operation.